The _retry property doesn't work in axios
I'm using axios version 1.6.7 but with an error 401 in the interceptor the refresh request is sent endlessly, an endless loop of requests is sent
const axiosParams = {
  baseUrl:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "http://localhost:8080" : "/",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
};

export const axiosInstance = axios.create(axiosParams);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (
      error.response &&
      error.response.status === 401
    ) {
      try {
        await store.dispatch("refreshToken", {
          refresh_token: getJwtTokens().refreshToken,
        });

        if (store.getters.getRefreshTokenIsSuccess) {
          axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common[
            "Authorization"
          ] = `Bearer ${store.getters.getTokens.access_token}`;
          originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${store.getters.getTokens.access_token}`;
          originalRequest.headers.ContentType = "application/json";
          originalRequest._retry = true;
        } else {
          router.push("/auth");
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        return axiosInstance.request(originalRequest);
      } catch (error) {
        router.push("/auth");
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
